# HTTP Status 304 when loading SVG in IE9

Tags: http, svg, internet-explorer-9, http-status-code-304

I get an HTTP Status 304 when loading SVG's into my webpage using IE9. The SVG's have never been loaded before so they should not be in the cache.

I have read alot  of topics and so far I've tried fiddling with the IE 9 options and adding `meta` tags.
I've also read that appending a random string to  your HTTP request can solve the problem. For example

> "?string=Randomstring"

However I'm not sure how to do this since the request is triggered by an `img` tag.

When I open the url to the svg it displays fine.
Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Your `<img>` tag has a `src` attribute containing the URL of the image file. Add `?string=whatever` to the end of this URL. Or, just clear your browser cache.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I have tried both, cleared cache nummerous times. But to no avail

Comment: If you've emptied the browser cache and are still getting a `304 Not modified` response from the server at the first visit, then either (a) your browser is at fault, or (b) you're doing something wrong. I'm afraid it's impossible to say anything more based on the information you provided.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage alot  of this aree wrong with IE9, and caching is one of those bugged features. I hope there is another workaround out there